# Is there any way to harcode Linux kernel boot options?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bootloader

I am working on SoC and I need to pass the kernel root partition name:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

I can not pass it via `uEnv.txt`. Is there any way to pass this boot option using the kernel configuration files or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via your bootloader. I am going to assume you are using the most common bootloader for SoC's: U-Boot. U-Boot has a variable called `bootargs` that normally holds all the [command line options](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxKernelArgs) for the kernel (like `root=`). To append bootargs with what you want, you would enter the following in the U-Boot prompt

```
setenv bootargs $(bootargs) root=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

If you want to permanently save the variable then you need to enter the command `saveenv` to tell U-Boot to save this change to disk. After this you can issue your normal boot commands.